# How to use a counter variable and the last row value in key title

Tags: gnuplot

I want to use my counter variable, the first and the last entry in the column, which have the time format"%H:%M:%S" in my plot in the key title, I know how to use variables in the key title, but not with with the date or time format. Also the counter is always zero in the key title. How can I evaluate it in the title after the plot is done?

```
c=0
plot 'data.txt' using (c=c+1,$1):3
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming I understand your question correctly, you want your counter and the first and the last date in the key. One possible way would be to do it in a two times pass. The first plot command actually plots nothing but is getting the desired values into variables. Maybe there are simpler ways to do it.

**Edit:** instead of originally `$0==0` it's better to use `c==0`, especially when your data might have single or multiple empty lines.

**Explanation:**

```
(c==0 ? Start=timecolumn(1,myTimeFmt) : End=timecolumn(1,myTimeFmt)):(c=c+1,NaN) not
```

Check `help operators ternary` and `help operators binary`.

A plot command is basically looping the rows of the given column(s).
If `c` equals `0` (which is the case only at the beginning of the loop) assign the time value of column 1 to the variable `Start`,
else assign the time value of column 1 to the variable `End`. At the end of the loop `End` will contain the last value of column 1.
The result of this ternary operator `(c==0? a:b)` will basically be the x-value to plot. However, the y-value is `NaN`, because `(c=c+1,NaN)` is a serial evaluation, i.e. `c` will be increased, but the result will be `NaN`. `NaN` will not be plotted, so the first plot command will plot nothing. `not` is the abbreviation for `notitle`, i.e. no keyentry. I hope is a bit clearer now.

**Code:**

```
### get datavalues into the key
reset session

$Data <<EOD
16:01:00   1.2   1.3
16:16:00   2.2   2.3
16:31:00   3.2   3.3
16:46:00   4.2   4.3
17:01:00   5.2   5.3
17:16:00   6.2   6.3
17:31:00   7.2   7.3
EOD

myTimeFmt = "%H:%M:%S"
set format x "%H:%M" time
set key top left
c=0

plot $Data u (c==0?Start=timecolumn(1,myTimeFmt):End=timecolumn(1,myTimeFmt)):(c=c+1,NaN) not, \
     $Data u (timecolumn(1,myTimeFmt)):3 w lp pt 7 \
     title sprintf("Count %d: ",c)." from ".strftime(myTimeFmt,Start)." to ".strftime(myTimeFmt,End)
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Addition:** (x-axis counts and y-axis time, calculation of duration)

**Code:**

```
### get datavalues into the key
reset session

$Data <<EOD
16:01:00   1.2   1.3
16:16:00   2.2   2.3
16:31:00   3.2   3.3
16:46:00   4.2   4.3
17:01:00   5.2   5.3
17:16:00   6.2   6.3
17:31:00   7.2   7.3
EOD

myTimeFmt = "%H:%M:%S"
set format y "%H:%M" time
set key at graph 0.5, 0.9
set offsets graph 0.05, graph 0.05, graph 0.05, graph 0.05
c=0

plot $Data u (c=c+1,NaN):(c==1?Start=timecolumn(1,myTimeFmt):End=timecolumn(1,myTimeFmt)) notitle, \
     $Data u ($0+1):(timecolumn(1,myTimeFmt)) w lp pt 7 \
      title sprintf("Counts %d",c)."\n from ".strftime(myTimeFmt,Start)." to ".strftime(myTimeFmt,End)."\nDuration: ".strftime("%tH:%M",End-Start)
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could you explain pls what the first  plot line does (c==0?Start=timecolumn(1,myTimeFmt):End=timecolumn(1,myTimeFmt)):(c=c+1,NaN) not ?

Comment: see modified answer.

Comment: Hello theozh, Is it possible to plot a value of the time column over each counter value? So basically that x value is the counter and the y value is the time? Also, what type is 'Start' and 'End'? I tried to use them to calculate the duration but gnuplot says that they are not defined.

Comment: How have you tried to calculate the duration? `Start` and `End` are only defined after the plot command. I will add some more code.

Comment: c=0
plot 'dat.txt' u (c==0?Start=column(2):End=column(2)):(c+1,NaN) not, \
   'dat.txt' u 1:2 t sprintf("Count %d: ",c)
print(End-Start)
I tried it with integer values this time. The counter is zero in the key title and the End is not defined. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you are not increasing the counter with `c+1`, you need `c=c+1`. You cannot print in the title you need to concatenate with `.` and use `sprintf()`. See modified code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209513/discussion-between-namal-and-theozh).